# Radio button and check box checked, depending on value on the top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this page depending on the val on the top of the page, select check boxes are shown or hidden.

If Value is VAL then check boxes are shown and only after selecting the check box, values get populated in the text area. So far it works.

Now if the Value is MAR then the check boxes will be hidden. This is where values are not populating in the text area.

Help is much appreciated. [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/gFvT7/2/)

```
$('table').find("input[type=radio]:checked:enabled").each(function () {
    if($('table').find("input[type=checkbox][name='" + $(this).attr('name') + "']").is(':checked')) {
        // See if we have a text box, if so use the text
        var $text = $(this).parent().find('textarea.m-notes:visible');
        var missingReason = $(this).parent().find('.reason').val();
        // Find closest ancestor with an id
        var selectedId = $(this).closest('[id]').attr('id');
        var value = selectedId + "~" + $(this).val();
        if ($text.length)
        {
            value += "~" + missingReason +"~" + $text.val();
        }
        clicked.push(value);
    }
}); //checked

// Display the selected ids 
$("#inputhere").val(clicked.join('|'));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "depending on the val on the top of the page" ?

Comment: On the top of the page, in the class header, if the text is VAL then show checkbox or if it is MAR then hide check boxes and when the radio button is clicked get its value, it rowid etc not of all the checked radio button

Comment: Ok, so put the code here, this will be better to help you. Then, you talk about checkboxes, I see no checkbox on your fiddle.

Comment: Hi! if you change the text in .header (top) to MAR and then VAL then you will see the check box shown or hidden.

http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/gFvT7/5/  Check box shows and this bit works

http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/gFvT7/6/ Checkbox is hidden and when radio button is clicked it populates all the checked radio button

Comment: Ok, so what are you trying to do ?

Comment: jsfiddle.net/19eggs/gFvT7/6 Here when you click the radio buttons only the values of the radio button clicked should show up. If you click the radio button on the first row, all the checked radio button values shows up in the textarea  at the end.

Comment: Oh ok, that's not clear at all.

Comment: That works fine on Chrome / Mac. When I click on a radio, only its own value is shown.

Comment: Strange. When I click Met radio button in the first row, it shows 14001290~01~01~CY|15489587~03~01~00|87554585~02~04~00 it should show only 14001290~01~01~CY and if another radio button in 2nd row is clicked eg Not Met it should show 14001290~01~01~CY|15489587~03~01~CN

Comment: If they Missing RdBtn on the 3rd Row, it should show 14001290~01~01~CY|15489587~03~01~CN|87554585~02~04~CM~1~Test